# PDO SQLite cannot bind NOT IN expression

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$dbh = new \PDO('sqlite:');
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$goodSql = 'SELECT number FROM (SELECT 1 number UNION SELECT 2) numbers WHERE number not in (2)';
echo json_encode($dbh->query($goodSql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM));

$badSql = 'SELECT number FROM (SELECT 1 number UNION SELECT 2) numbers WHERE number not in (?)';
$binds = ['2'];
$statement = $dbh->prepare($badSql);
$statement->execute($binds);
echo json_encode($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM));
?>
```

The first statement successfully excludes `2` from the result. The exclusion is specified by an inline SQL condition `NOT IN (2)`.

The second statement fails to exclude `2` from the result. The exclusion is specified by a PDO bind of the parameter `2` in a condition `NOT IN (?)`.

In PDO/MySQL, the two statements produce identical results.

What is happening? Is this a bug or is this outcome documented?

P.S. I have tested this on all PHP versions using https://3v4l.org/otfDj and got identical results with 5.6.0 - 5.6.30, 7.0.0 - 7.2.0alpha2.

Answer (score 3):

This is because [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-parameters) treats passed parameters as strings.

So, your query becomes

```
$badSql = 'SELECT number FROM (SELECT 1 number UNION SELECT 2) numbers WHERE number not in ("2")';
```

Definitely, there no results that equals "2".

Solution is to bind params explicilty like `int`:

```
$badSql = 'SELECT number FROM (SELECT 1 number UNION SELECT 2) numbers WHERE number not in (?)';
$binds = ['2'];
$statement = $dbh->prepare($badSql);
$statement->bindValue(1, '2', PDO::PARAM_INT);   // this is it
$statement->execute();
echo json_encode($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM));
```

Comment: Wouldn't the comparison fall into `In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.` and be the same? (... or maybe this is specific to sqllite, thats from mysql, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)

Comment: Not sure how this works internally, can this rules be apllied to evaluating `IN` clause. But even if both arguments are converted to floats, then they probably will not be equal too.